# Is a possible to create "indexed view" for query where using CDC functions?

Tags: t-sql, indexing, view, sql-server-2012, cdc

I attempting to create indexed view for result of cdc function. The original query is big and complex. Below is simplified version of query that generate same error:

```
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;  
SET ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ARITHABORT,  
    QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS ON;  
GO  
--Create view with schemabinding.  
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.view_Test', 'view') IS NOT NULL  
DROP VIEW dbo.view_Test;  
GO  
CREATE VIEW dbo.view_Test 
WITH SCHEMABINDING  
AS

SELECT 
kz.__$start_lsn,
    kz.__$seqval,
    kz.__$operation AS operation,
    kz.__$update_mask,
    kz.GUID,
    kz.typezalezh,
    kz.category,
    kz.zone,
    kz.area,
    kz.Volume
 FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_EXT_GeolObject_KategZalezh(sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_EXT_GeolObject_KategZalezh'), sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn(), 'all') AS kz
 GO
```

This query return the folowing error:

> Cannot schema bind view 'dbo.view_Test'.
>   'cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_EXT_GeolObject_KategZalezh' is not
>   schema bound.

I read that

> if you want to create an index on a view or you want to preserve the
>   base table schema once a view has been defined, in both these cases
>   you have to use the "WITH SCHEMABINDING" clause to bind the view to
>   the schema of the base tables

In original query i using `dbo` and `cdc` schemas here i'm using only `cdc` schema. But i whant create view in `dbo` dchema.
Also I'm using CDC function and not using cdc tables directly like recommend by Microsoft.

I read about a few things to consider when creating indexed view:

- You can not create an index on a view with outer joins used in it, even if you use schema binding
- You can not create an index on a view with outer joins used in it, even if you use schema binding
- You can not use '*' in the select statement of a view when it is schema bound.
- You will not be able to create clustered index on a view if the view references any nondeterministic functions.
- You can not use aggregate functions when using schema binding.
- You can not migrate the base table of a schema bound view.

As I understand, my query is fit to this rules. But I do not know for sure whether CDC function is deterministic or nondeterministic.

Is a possible to create "indexed view" for query where using CDC functions?

Answer (score 1):

No, CDC functions isn't "schemabinding" so view, that relies on it, can't be indexed at all. Instead, you can create a table and fill it from function periodically.

Suppose, you have table "testdb.dbo.Customers_for_cdc_test" that is CDC enabled. You can materialize CDC function by code:

```
use testdb
go
select top (0) *
  into dbo.SOURCE_NAME_changes
  from cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_Customers_for_CDC_test
       (
         sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_Customers_for_cdc_test')
       , sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn()
       , N'all'
       ) as src
;
create index IX__dbo__SOURCE_NAME_changes
  on dbo.SOURCE_NAME_changes
  (
    __$start_lsn asc
  )
;
-- Other needed indices can be here.
go
```

Table filling can be implemented as a job. Set job schedule for periodically start. The job itself may contain only one step that calls filling procedure

```
use testdb
go
exec dbo.sp_append_new_SOURCE_NAME_changes
```

where "dbo.sp_append_new_SOURCE_NAME_changes" is

```
use testdb
go
create procedure dbo.sp_append_new_SOURCE_NAME_changes
  as
  begin
    set nocount on
    ;
    declare @max_old_lsn    as binary(10) 
          , @min_old_lsn    as binary(10)
          , @min_active_lsn as binary(10) = sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_Customers_for_CDC_test')
          , @max_active_lsn as binary(10) = sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn()
    ;
    select @max_old_lsn = coalesce(max(__$start_lsn) ,cast(0 as binary(10)))
         , @min_old_lsn = coalesce(min(__$start_lsn) ,cast(0 as binary(10)))
      from dbo.SOURCE_NAME_changes
    ;
    if (@min_old_lsn < @min_active_lsn
    ) begin
        delete from dbo.SOURCE_NAME_changes
          where __$start_lsn < @min_active_lsn
        ;
      end
    if (@max_old_lsn < @max_active_lsn
    ) begin
        declare @min_lsn as binary(10) = iif(@min_active_lsn < @max_old_lsn ,@max_old_lsn ,@min_active_lsn) -- Speed up
        ;
        insert into dbo.SOURCE_NAME_changes
          --(COLUMN_LIST)
          select * --(COLUMN_LIST)
            from cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_Customers_for_CDC_test
                 (
                   @min_lsn
                 , @max_active_lsn
                 , N'all'
                 ) as src
            where src.__$start_lsn > @max_old_lsn -- Because the max old lsn is already in.
          ;
      end
  end
go
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought about it. One question. Can I create an indexed view from a simple view?

Comment: Yes, you can create index when your view meets some restrictions. Restrictions and a great example can be found here [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views).